# How do I pull the ASIN code from an Amazon url in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I pull the ASIN code from an Amazon url in Excel?

Variable length URL's, example:

Want to derive the cell result : B00BQ59SYM

from this

[http://www.amazon.com/Dyna-Glo-DGB730SNB-D-Dual-Fuel-Grill/dp/B00BQ59SYM/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1428647284&sr=8-7&keywords=hybrid+grill](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQ59SYM)

But could also be from this URL to the same location:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00BQ59SYM?psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQ59SYM)

Comment: Probably you need to use regular expressions (e.g. regEx add-in).

Comment: It's everything after the first `/dp/` and up to either a `/`, a `?`, or the end of the URL.

Answer (score 5):

`=MID(A1,FIND("dp/",A1)+3,10)`
Place your url in A1

Answer (score -1):

Slightly unrelated - but if you are doing Google Spreadsheet this can be done using

> =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)")

I am sure similar regex may work in Excel too.

Answer (score -2):

For Google Sheets 
I have tested the code
It works with ";" instead ","

so

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)")

Comment: ; and , are just different list separating symbols. `;` is used in locales where comma is used for radix point like most European languages. It's unrelated to Google sheet